# Proving an identity related to the torsion of a connection.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\nabla$ be a connection, and let $T(X,Y) = \nabla_{X}Y - \nabla_{Y}X - [X,Y]$ be the torsion of $\nabla$. I am trying to prove that if $f$ is a smooth function, then $fT(X,Y) = T(fX,Y)$. Using the fact that $\nabla_{Y}fX = Y(f)X + f\nabla_{Y}X$ and $[fX,gY] = fg[X,Y] + fX(g)Y - gY(f)X$ I have the following:

\begin{align} fT(X,Y) &= f(\nabla_{X}Y - \nabla_{Y}X - [X,Y]) \notag\\ &= f\nabla_{X}Y - f\nabla_{Y}X - f[X,Y] \notag\\ &= f\nabla_{X}Y - (\nabla_{Y}fX - Y(f)X) - f[X,Y] \notag\\ &= \nabla_{fX}Y - (\nabla_{Y}fX - Y(f)X) - ([fX,Y] - fXY + Y(f)X)\notag\\ &= \nabla_{fX}Y - \nabla_{Y}fX - [fX,Y] - fXY \end{align} Now I can't see where to proceed. Since $T(fX,Y) = \nabla_{fX}Y - \nabla_{Y}fX - [fX,Y]$ it seems as though $fXY$ should be 0, but I can't figure out why this should be the case. Any help would be appreciated! I feel like I'm just missing some little trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think the term $fXY$ should really be $fX(1)Y$.  And $X(1) = 0$.  ($fXY$ doesn't really mean anything.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Stephen Montgomery

For Leibinz's law

$$X(fg)=X(f)g+fX(g)$$

For $f=1=g$ have  $X(1)=X(1)1+1X(1)=2X(1)$, then $X(1) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is really more natural to start from $T(fX,Y)$:

\begin{align}
T(fX,Y) &= \nabla_{fX} Y - \nabla_Y (fX) - [fX,Y] \\
&= f\nabla_X Y - ((Y.f)X + f\nabla_Y X) - (f[X,Y] - (Y.f)X) \\
&= fT(X,Y).
\end{align}

Remark also that there is an interpretation of the formula $[X,fY] = (X.f)Y + f[X,Y]$. If you know about Lie derivatives, this is just the equality $[X,fY] =L_X(fY) = (L_X f) Y + f L_X Y = (X.f)Y + f[X,Y]$. A bracket should be thought as a kind of derivation. Using the antisymmetry of the bracket, you can find the more general formula 
\begin{align}
[fX,gY] &= ((fX).g) Y + g[fX,Y] \\
 &= f(X.g)Y - g[Y,fX] \\
 &= f(X.g)Y - g(Y.f)X + fg[X,Y].
\end{align}